# simplexml_load_file result. I need help extracting the error message from this returned XML message

Tags: php, file, load, simplexml

I am receiving the following XML message when the site I'm communicationg with is down for maintenance, I need to detect and retrieve the error message "xxxxxxxxx.com is temporarily unavailable while we perform regular system maintenance". Hope someonme can help!

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
  [head] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [meta] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
      [@attributes] => Array ( 
        [http-equiv] => Content-Type 
        [content] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 
      ) 
    ) 
    [title] => Updates In Progress 
    [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
      [@attributes] => Array ( 
        [href] => style/style.css 
        [rel] => stylesheet 
        [type] => text/css 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
  [body] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [div] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
      [@attributes] => Array (
        [id] => container 
      ) 
      [div] => Array (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
          [@attributes] => Array ( 
            [id] => header 
          ) 
          [img] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [@attributes] => Array ( 
              [src] => images/top_banner.jpg 
              [alt] => xxx Freight | Updates In Progress 
            ) 
          ) 
        ) 
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
          [@attributes] => Array ( 
            [id] => wrapper 
          ) 
          [div] => Array ( 
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
              [@attributes] => Array ( 
                [id] => leftCol 
              ) 
              [p] => Array ( 
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                  [strong] => SYSTEM MAINTENANCE 
                ) 
                [1] => xxxxxx.com is temporarily unavailable while we perform regular system maintenance. 
                [2] => We're sorry for the inconvenience. Please check back soon. 
              ) 
            ) 
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
              [@attributes] => Array ( 
                [id] => rightCol 
              ) 
              [p] => For immediate assistance, please contact Customer Service at 1-800-610-6500. 
            ) 
            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
              [@attributes] => Array ( 
                [class] => clearfloat 
              ) 
            ) 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: If you copied this `var_dump()` output from the browser, please view the _page source_ in the browser and copy/paste it from there, where it will have proper indentation and line breaks.  It is unreadable in this format.  Then highlight it in the box above and Ctrl-k to format as a code block./

Comment: I've reformatted the copypasted `print_r` output, still not too readable. Please paste the original html(?) response as well.

Comment: I think its better you just add the XML response

Answer (score 0):

Try using [simpexml_tree()](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug/blob/master/simplexml_tree.php) to output your SimpleXML object. The output it gives should hint at the operations you need to find the node you want.

However, be aware that SimpleXML will only work if your input is valid XML, and this is HTML, which is not guaranteed to be valid XML.

If possible, check the HTTP status being returned from the server (e.g. using the CURL `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` option) and see if the server returns a standard 5xx status when it's down. (Usually 500 or 503).